# Normal with infinite variance

Tags: distributions

I have a normal distribution with support $[a,b]$ $(a < 0 < b)$ with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. I am wondering if $\sigma^2 \rightarrow \infty$, the normal distribution tends to a uniform $U(a,b)$.

Any idea?

I guess I can't suppose this support instead of $\mathbb{R}$. But graphically, as variance increases, the pdf turns flat. So, if the support is $\mathbb{R}$, I guess that pdf is zero for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. That is why I think that with support $[a,b]$, maybe it converges to a uniform.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! So you have a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)?

Comment: Yes. Imagine that a and b are in the tails so that truncated is very similar to the original.

Comment: [_Mathematica_ says the answer is **yes**.](https://imgur.com/a/U3CkqQ8)

Comment: @JuanCamilo could you update/edit your question with the information whether or not you refer to a truncated normal distribution. It remains confusing like this. For instance, what does the $\sigma$ parameter refer to? What do you mean when you say 'normal distribution', which occurs once in the title and twice in the text?

Comment: This result has little to do with Normality.  If you take literally any distribution whose CDF is continuously differentiable at $0,$ rescale it by $\sigma^2,$ and truncate it at $a\lt0\lt b,$ then the limiting distribution will be uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by taking the ratio of the value at zero (the max of the distribution, if it's a truncated mean-zero Gaussian) to that of one of the ends, say $b$:

$$
\frac{f(0)}{f(b)} = \exp\left(b^2 / 2 \sigma^2 \right),
$$

where $f(x)$ is the truncated Normal distribution in question. In the limit, as $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$ we get,

$$
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(0)}{f(b)} = 1.
$$

That is, the ratio of the peak of the distribution to the far-right end approaches $1.$ You can show this similarly for the ratio of the peak to $a$. If $f(a) = f(0) = f(b),$ and $f$ is non-increasing in either direction from $0$ (which is true if it's a mean-$0$ truncated Normal distribution with $a < 0 < b$), then $f$ is the same everywhere in $[a,b].$

If we assume, as well, that $f$ remains a probability distribution as $\sigma$ increases, which means that we properly truncate the denominator by the proper normalization factor that depends on $\sigma$, then, clearly, the distribution approaches $U(a,b).$